# Scrollbar not appearing in Tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi so basically I want to create an online examination portal similar to Mettl,TCS ION,etc which will have two frames one which will contain the name,registration id,etc and another frame would contain an array of buttons which serve as the question navigation buttons(basically they show whether you have visited the question ,etc) and a canvas sort of frame which will have the question and mcq options.I wanted to implement the scrollbar just to the right of the canvas frame but the scrollbar is not visible the code is given below

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

testportalscreen = Tk()
testportalscreen.geometry("1366x768")
testportalscreen['bg']='white'
frame = LabelFrame(testportalscreen,padx=20,pady=80)  ##Create a frame for button
frame.place(x=0,y=149,width=500,height=768)

button_pic = Image.open("C:\PYTHON IDE\Button_pic.jpg")
new_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(button_pic)
question_button = [[None]*10]*10
frame2 = LabelFrame(testportalscreen,padx=4,pady=9) ##LeftCorner_frame_for name,roll no,etc
frame2.place(x=0,y=-7,width=500,height=200)
my_canvas = Canvas(testportalscreen)

scrollbar_1 = Scrollbar(testportalscreen,orient="vertical",command=my_canvas.yview)
scrollbar_1.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
my_canvas.place(x=500,y=0,height=1000,width=837)
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_1.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox('all')))

for i in range(6):
for j in range(8):
    question_button[i][j] = Button(frame, image=new_pic, compound=TOP, width=50)
    question_button[i][j].grid(column=j,row=i)

testportalscreen.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aUl2.png)

The link shows the output

Comment: The scrollbar is shown at the right side of window in the image.

Comment: Why do you use `place` for the canvas? In most cases it is easier to use `pack` or `grid` so that you don't have to calculate manually the space taken by each widget to avoid overlaps or resizing issues.

Comment: I know that  but the scrollbar box is not visible acw1668

Comment: Please provide a solution if possible ASAP

Comment: It is because there is nothing inside the canvas, so the `scrollregion` is smaller than the size of canvas.

Comment: I took your advice and put some text in the canvas but the scroll bar box
 is still not visible.If you could please do the necessary changes in the code in order to achieve the same

Comment: Try adding `my_canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 600, 1500, fill="blue")` and you will see the scrollbar working.

Comment: Ya its working now thanks!!...but the frame aint moving down could you provide some tips regards that sorry I'm a huge noob in tkinter